# Hacker Experience password not working!

Tags: hacker-experience

So I recently started playing the online game "Hacker Experience" I've started mission 1 where you have to hack someone and the username and password is Usernme: Root Password: deI1KDXt. But when I enter them it says incorrect password even though it is correct? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What probably happened is that the person changed their password. You can just brute force it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try brute-forcing the server yet? Internet -> IP -> Hack -> Brute Force

Do you have your cracker installed? Software -> Cracker.ckr (1.0) -> Install

Otherwise, this might be a bug, please report it to the mods via the fourms. -> https://forum.hackerexperience.com/viewforum.php?f=19